# How download image from URL to django?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-forms

I want to load an image by URL, but only the URL itself is saved to the model, how can I specify the path to save to the media folder, and how do I save it at all?

```
from django.db import models
import urllib.request
from urllib.parse import urlparse

upload_path = 'media/'

class Image(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=upload_path, null= True, blank=True)
    image_url = models.URLField(blank=True, null=True)

    def get_image(self):
        name = urlparse(str(self.image)).path.split('/')[-1]
        urllib.request.urlretrieve(str(self.image_url), 'img\media\media' + name + '.jpg')
```

Comment: No, not only the URL is saved to the model. An `ImageField` saves the *filepath*, and saves the object in the `MEDIA_ROOT`. But nevertheless this will indeed not work, since you basically ask to download a file that is already *in* your media directory.

Comment: @messageman it's generally bad to upload a screenshot of code.  Instead, you should copy/paste your code into the question.  Use 4 spaces before to make it format as code.  This will allow search engines to index based on the code and other people to copy/paste your code. please update your question

Comment: The signature of the function does not look ok. Normally it should take a parameter `url` that specifies *where* to fetch the item from. By using `image.url`, you obtain the url of the image already there (if it exists), and thus in the best case, you download the image from your own webserver.

Comment: @J'e uploaded to pastebin

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem How should I do then? Can you tell me please?

Comment: download and upload image!

Comment: @Wertartem how? Tell me pls

Comment: @messageman  How do you upload a image to django?

Comment: @Wertartem ye, download from URL and upload to django, pls

Answer (score 5):

You can download the image of a given URL and then upload it through a `NamedTemporaryFile`:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from django.core.files import File
from django.core.files.temp import NamedTemporaryFile

class ObjectWithImageField(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=upload_path, null= True, blank=True)
    image_url = models.URLField(blank=True, null=True)
    
    def get_image_from_url(self, url):
       img_tmp = NamedTemporaryFile(delete=True)
       with urlopen(url) as uo:
           assert uo.status == 200
           img_tmp.write(uo.read())
           img_tmp.flush()
       img = File(img_tmp)
       self.image.save(img_tmp.name, img)
       self.image_url = url
```

You can then thus make an image with:

```
my_obj = ObjectWithImageField()
my_obj.get_image_from_url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/PIFN0.jpg')
my_obj.save()
```

Comment: does this apply to only images?

Comment: @CynthiaOnyilimba: it will normally also work for `FileField`s.

Comment: Got bad request `Detected path traversal attempt in '/tmp/tmp8zcwbiwz'`

Comment: That is because the path should be relative to the `MEDIA_ROOT`. You thus should work with a `self.image.save('some_filename.ext', img)` with `some_filename.ext`, a *relative* path.